# Converting misspelled words to actual words

Tags: nlp, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I'm doing a project on NLP, I want to find words most prominent in a corpus, when I count the frequencies of all the words, words like `"thi", "realli", "happi", "babi"` emerges, In my processing pipeline, No matter if I lemmatize or stemm, same result, can someone tell me how to turn these into actual words or something about lemmatizing or stemming.

Comment: can you share the relevant section of your code?

Comment: @Bitswazsky thx but I found that it was actually python NLTK's stemming engine, for whatever reason converting really -> realli, happy -> happi